# AES padding and writing the ciphertext to a disk file

Tags: c#, c++, encryption, padding, crypto++

I have a string which I encrypt with the following mehtod in C++ using Crypto++:

```cpp
std::ifstream t(filename); //File to be encrypt
std::stringstream buffer;
buffer << t.rdbuf();

ofstream combined_file2(filename2); //Encrypted file
combined_file2 << encrypt(buffer.str());

string encrypt(string data)
{
  // Key and IV setup
  std::string key = "0123456789abcdef";
  std::string iv = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";

  //Alternative
  //byte key[CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH], iv[CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE];
  //memset(key, 0x00, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
  //memset(iv, 0x00, CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE);

  std::string plaintext = data;
  std::string ciphertext;

  // Create Cipher Text
  CryptoPP::AES::Encryption aesEncryption((byte *)key.c_str(), CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
  CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Encryption cbcEncryption(aesEncryption, (byte *)iv.c_str());

  //Alternative
  //CryptoPP::AES::Encryption aesEncryption(key, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
  //CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Encryption cbcEncryption(aesEncryption, iv);

  CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfEncryptor(cbcEncryption, new CryptoPP::StringSink(ciphertext));
  stfEncryptor.Put(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(plaintext.c_str()), plaintext.length() + 1);
  stfEncryptor.MessageEnd();

  return ciphertext;
}
```

When I try to decrypt the file in my C# Application, I get the message, that the length of the data is invalid. I think that the lenght of th byte array isn't a multiple of 16, so I get the error. I try to use a padding, but it is not working right.

Here is how I decrypt the file:

```cs
string plaintext = Decrypt(File.ReadAllBytes(path));

private static string Decrypt(byte[] cipherText)
{
   if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
       throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
   byte[] Key = GetBytes(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["aes_key"]);
   byte[] IV = GetBytes(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["aes_iv"]);

   // Declare the string used to hold the decrypted text.
   string plaintext = null;

   // Create an RijndaelManaged object with the specified key and IV.
   using (RijndaelManaged rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged())
   {
     rijAlg.Key = Key;
     //rijAlg.IV = IV;
     //for testing                
     rijAlg.IV = new byte[] { 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97 };

    // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
    ICryptoTransform decryptor = rijAlg.CreateDecryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);

    // Create the streams used for decryption.
    using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
    {
      using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
      {
        using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
        {
          // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
          // and place them in a string.
          plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return plaintext;
}
```

How can I solve the problem? Is there any function to do the padding, or maybe padding is the wrong way?

Comment: How do you transfer the ciphertext from the C++ side to the C# side?

Comment: In C++ I save a file `combined_file2 << encrypt(buffer.str());` which I read in my C# program `string plaintext = Decrypt(File.ReadAllBytes(path));`

Comment: Usually you get this kind of exception if - somewhere in the chain - the ciphertext is converted to a string instead of binary.

Comment: I'm using this example for the encryption: http://programmingknowledgeblog.blogspot.de/2013/04/compiling-and-integrating-crypto-into.html I also test it without the +1 but the problem still exists. The ciphertext is byte[238533].

Comment: For CBC (and ECB) the ciphertext needs to be a multiple of the blocksize (16 bytes in case of AES) unless ciphertext stealing is used (which it isn't). A ciphertext of 238533 is obviously not correct.

Comment: This was also my thought. But how can I fix it? If I'm right, I need to do this during the encryption, but I don't know how and I can't find any approache.

Comment: Can you show us how you safe the string? What size is the string directly after encryption? Note that the null terminator *should not be used* to determine the size, the string should be treated as bytes.

Comment: You can find the code in the first code block. I use a stringbuffer to read the file and a ofstream to write the encrypted string.

Comment: @n-3 - How did you make out on this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment:

> In C++ I save a file combined_file2 << encrypt(buffer.str()); which I
>   read in my C# program string plaintext =
>   Decrypt(File.ReadAllBytes(path));

I don't think embedded NULLs is causing problems from the `encrypt` function since its returning a `string`, and that includes an explicit length.

However, an embedded NULL and the way the file is being written to disk in C++ (or read from disk in C#) will be a problem since this will stop at the first embedded NULL: `combined_file2 << encrypt(buffer.str())`.

Perhaps something like the following would be helpful:

```
StringSource ss(ciphertext, true /*pumpAll*/);
FileSink fs("my-encrypted-file.bin", true /*binary*/);
ss.TransferTo(fs);
```

If you are using a C++ stream, then use the `write` method on the stream object:

```
ofstream combined_file2;
...
combined_file2.write(ciphertext.data(), ciphertext.size());
```